# Merge material-ui overrides

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to merge `overrides` of two themes but have not got it working.

So I have common settings:

```
const commonSettings = {

    spacing: 10,
    overrides: {
        MuiButton: {
            root: {
                textTransform: "uppercase",
                borderRadius: 6
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And theme settings:

```
const themeSettings = {

    overrides: {
        MuiAppBar: {
            colorPrimary: {
                backgroundColor: "#333",
                color: "#FFF"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Merging the theme:

```
const lightTheme = createMuiTheme({ ...commonSettings, ...themeSettings });
```

So `spacing` will get added to the merged theme from `commonSettings`, it works as expected but I can't get the `overrides` values to merge. The `override` from `themeSettings` will be used without the values from `commonSettings`. Is it possible to merge the `overrides` together?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so I got it working by inserting the `overrides` from the theme in the `commonSettings` as a standard object.

```
overrides: {

        MuiButton: {
            root: {
                textTransform: "none",
                borderRadius: 50
            }
        },

        ...(lightThemeOverrides)
    },
```